# alpha blending looking wrong/different on iPhone/Pad

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, opengl-es-2.0

I'm drawing some alpha blended sprites. I have the same assets rendering on Win32 using D3D and OpenGL, and the correct result looks like this when the vertex color is 0xFFFFFF and the background colour is 0xC0D0E0

[image: Cap1]

On Win32/OpenGL I enable blending as follows:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
```

and on Win32/D3D as follows:

```
CD3D11_BLEND_DESC blendDesc(D3D11_DEFAULT);
D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_BLEND_DESC rtBlendDesc;
rtBlendDesc.BlendEnable = true;
rtBlendDesc.BlendOp = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
rtBlendDesc.BlendOpAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
rtBlendDesc.DestBlend = D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
rtBlendDesc.DestBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ZERO;
rtBlendDesc.RenderTargetWriteMask = D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;
rtBlendDesc.SrcBlend = D3D11_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA;
rtBlendDesc.SrcBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ZERO;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0] = rtBlendDesc;
gDevice->CreateBlendState(&blendDesc, &mBlendState);
```

then, at render time:

```
gContext->OMSetBlendState(mBlendState, NULL, 0xffffffff);
```

On Win32/OpenGL I use the fixed function pipeline, and on DX11 I use very simple vert/pixel shaders:

```
float4 SpritePixelShader(PS_INPUT input) : SV_Target
{
    return (txDiffuse.Sample(samLinear, input.Tex)) * input.Col;
}

PS_INPUT SpriteVertexShader(VS_INPUT input)
{
    PS_INPUT output = (PS_INPUT)0;
    output.Pos = mul(float4(input.Pos.x, input.Pos.y, 0.5, 1.0), projection);
    output.Tex = input.Tex;
    output.Col = input.Col;
    return output;
}
```

All well and good. OpenGL and D3D give me identical results.

On OpenGL ES 2.0 on the iPhone simulator (not sure if this is a simulator thing or not, I can't test on a device yet):

I enable blending similarly:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
```

My fragment/vertex shaders are similar:

```
// fragment shader
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = color * texture2D(s_texture, texCoord);
}

// vertex shader
void main()
{
    color = vertexColor;
    texCoord = vertexTexCoord;
    gl_Position = matrix * vec4(vertexPosition, 0, 1);
}
```

But I get this:

[image: Cap2]

Which seems to be using modulate rather than additive. I've tried calling:

```
glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD);
```

but that doesn't seem to do anything, nor does

```
glBlendEquationOES(GL_FUNC_ADD_OES);
```

If I use:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

then it looks right but the alpha component of the vertex colors is ignored (and I need it to be used).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!
Charlie.

Comment: Or, put another way, what is the name of the blend mode activated by this call: glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); ?